# Omit spread of properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an Omitted type in Typescript. I've added a comment for what type I need (`DesiredType`), and what type I'm getting (type `never`). Thanks in advance!

```js
interface IReport {
  start: Date
  end: Date
  name: string
}

type ReportVariant = 'profit' | 'expense'

interface ProfitReport extends IReport {
  variant: 'profit'
  includeGrossProfit: boolean
}

interface ExpenseReport extends IReport {
  variant: 'expense'
  includeTaxes: boolean
}

type Report = { variant: ReportVariant } & (ProfitReport | ExpenseReport)

type DesiredType = Omit<Report, IReport>
// Expecting: { variant: 'profit', includeGrossProfit: boolean } | { variant: 'expense', includeTaxes: boolean }
// Actual: never
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code. The first one is a simple one, the second parameter to `Omit` must be a union of keys you want removed, so instead of `IReport` you probably want `keyof IReport`.

This is closer, but will not actually get you to the type you want. Since `Report` is a union, `Omit` will work on the common properties of `Report` not the union constituents and `Omit<Report, keyof IReport>` will just get you `{ variant: ReportVariant; }` which is not what you want.

What you actually want is to apply `Omit` on each union constituent. To do this you need to use the [distribution behavior of conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to take each union constituent and apply the transformation:

```
type Report = { variant: ReportVariant } & (ProfitReport | ExpenseReport)

type DistributedOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends T ? Omit<T, K> : never;
type DesiredType = DistributedOmit<Report, keyof IReport>
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=58&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIAcD2UzIDeAUMsgM5hz4BcyAInJKchCACZ2PNkhwC2EOpSigA5sQC+xYmACeWFJlz4AatWBxwyALzIA5Fig4YwMPuQAfAxAAeikOQj6ZoSLEQoACsdNhleAR2kBzkaAH4RCwAbhpaYHSGvmYuZKAIADYAruwQAOLG5OQ+JmZ0AEY4OBkQWlKu4NDwSMgAovZsThFBtiHsYRjYgVFksaLxiXYOTqnI6dm5ACpwthDkFVU1ddKyCkpDkXqEyGOa4HTd6uPaksgAZMgAFCV+3VZtHY4Q3QCUMvKKBjAETAcpZSDsADy-DMAB5FgAaZAAaVYvTY-WQJUU+DkyIgcgAfLpkIs0X0wmSAPzIaFwxEo4l0EAQaLQADcu0B9DWwCgEHYiz2JPowLAojBELpYFh3SRAGsCSZwgcwITiAB6DXIADKAhQcHWRBOcXOBiMpXMSPmOXyhWKyQSyEq1VqIGQt2sx1OExsnxm1pAmVty1WRpdW3d0iAA)

Answer (score 1):

Close. It is Actually:

```
type DesiredType = Omit<Report, keyof IReport>
```

Comment: That is one problem with the code, but since `Report` is  a union, the code above does not get to the desired type in the post.